# Multi master setup in kubernetes, weave net is not running properly

Tags: docker, kubernetes

We have try to setup multi master in kubernete our network plugin is not properly it’s showing below errors
[image]

I followed [this blog post](https://blog.inkubate.io/install-and-configure-a-multi-master-kubernetes-cluster-with-kubeadm/) for setup multi master in kubernetes,

Cluster information:

```
Kubernetes version: v14.3.0
Cloud being used: (put bare-metal if not on a public cloud) 
Installation method:
Host OS: 18.04.2
```

We are getting the error below after setup the weave net.

```
{"log":"ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E0701 07:51:53.278548   25716 reflector.go:205] github.com/weaveworks/weave/prog/weave-npc/main.go:321: Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500\u0026resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2019-07-01T07:51:53.278754803Z"}
{"log":"ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E0701 07:51:53.280424   25716 reflector.go:205] github.com/weaveworks/weave/prog/weave-npc/main.go:323: Failed to list *v1.NetworkPolicy: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/apis/networking.k8s.io/v1/networkpolicies?limit=500\u0026resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2019-07-01T07:51:53.280526951Z"}
{"log":"ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E0701 07:51:53.285744   25716 reflector.go:205] github.com/weaveworks/weave/prog/weave-npc/main.go:322: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/pods?limit=500\u0026resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2019-07-01T07:51:53.28588935Z"}
```

Below error we are getting after setup the Kube proxy.

```
{“log”:“E0701 07:57:20.105121 1 reflector.go:126] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:133: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://101.53.145.68:6443/api/v1/services?labelSelector=!service.kubernetes.io%2Fservice-proxy-name\u0026limit=500\u0026resourceVersion=0: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of “crypto/rsa: verification error” while trying to verify candidate authority certificate “kubernetes”)\n”,“stream”:“stderr”,“time”:“2019-07-01T07:57:20.105357775Z”}
{“log”:“E0701 07:57:20.107067 1 reflector.go:126] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:133: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get https://101.53.145.68:6443/api/v1/endpoints?labelSelector=!service.kubernetes.io%2Fservice-proxy-name\u0026limit=500\u0026resourceVersion=0: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of “crypto/rsa: verification error” while trying to verify candidate authority certificate “kubernetes”)\n”,“stream”:“stderr”,“time”:“2019-07-01T07:57:20.107170774Z”}
```

All the hostname are different,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do all of the nodes have different hostnames? can you do `kubectl get nodes -o wide` and update the question? Also, did you create the certificate on a different machine and copy it to your server? if yes, the time of the machine you used to generate the cert should match the time of the server that you're copying it to, else it will cause access issues.